# How to avoid water tension in a hose?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, flow, surface-tension, capillary-action

I am doing a project in which I have to flow water between two containers, which are connected at the bottom by a 1/4" hose. Remarkably, the surface water tension is such that water does not flow between the containers. I can see the water wall at the outtake of one of the containers, despite the fact that the other container is almost full with water. If I put a piece of adsorbent paper on the outtake, this brakes the surface tension and water flows well. Is there any other way to break the surface tension not requiring a chemical change of the water?. Like a design that maximizes surface?

Comment: Try one drop of liquid soap.  Soap is a surface active agent (surfactant), and is designed specifically to dramatically lower the surface tension of water.

Comment: Thanks David. do you know any other method that does not require to change the chemistry of the water?.

Comment: A picture or diagram might help.

Comment: @Camilo, the soap doesn't change the chemistry of water.  A soap molecule is comprised of a long hydrophobic tail and a short hydrophilic head.  The hydrophilic head physically associates with water and the hydrophobic tail physically associates with non-water substances (e.g., oil).  The physics of this situation acts at the water surface, not on the bulk fluid.

Answer (score 0):

1) shape the surface of the hose outlet into a large nozzle shape, broadening the surface that has to be held by surface tension

2) or extend the hose in a bit and cut it off at a shallow angle, again increasing the area that would have to be covered

3) put a valve between the two volumes and open it slowly, such that the hose isn’t full before flow is established

Answer (score 0):

increase the diameter of the hose to 1/2".